# Java Client Server program - client connection refused when I run client again and again

Tags: java, client-server, serversocket

hi the fallowing is my client program
this is a random client program
when I run it again and again I'm getting connection refused
but this is working when I run the program first time

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    try(Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",9651)){
        System.out.println("Enetr a number");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ip= sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("hello-----"+ip);
        PrintStream p= new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        p.println(ip);
        System.out.println("hello-----"+p);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( 
                new InputStreamReader( s.getInputStream()));
        //DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        int x= in.read();
        System.out.println("test test ----"+x);
        sc.close(); 
        s.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);

    }


}
```

my server program

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    int m;
    try(ServerSocket ss= new ServerSocket(9651)){
        System.out.println("server created at port 1321");
        try(Socket sk=ss.accept()){
            System.out.println("a connection is made with some client");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( 
                    new InputStreamReader( sk.getInputStream()));
            m=in.read();
            int q=doub(m);
            trade(q);
            PrintStream p = new PrintStream(sk.getOutputStream());
            p.println(q);

            System.out.println("testing....m"+m+"-----q"+q);
            sk.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        ss.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }



}

public static int doub(int x){
    System.out.println("calling the double method");
    int z=x*2;
    return z;

}
public static void trade(int y){
    if(y>=0){
        System.out.println("working well");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("quit the comp");

}
```

error o/p

```
Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Other than that, perhaps check the firewall. Sometimes loopbacks are not allowed. If the code exited that would be interesting.

Comment: Finally, try with resources should close anything that is running as if it were in a finally block so s.close in client is unecessary. The same goes for sk in server. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: HI Andrew, If  the issue is with firewall then I should not get the success o/p first time . I'm getting error when I run it again and again